# Essl epush server setup issue on amazon ec2 centos

Tags: tomcat, networking, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install iclock (epush server from esslsecurity) and it is working fine on my local system.

But when i am trying to install it on our production server (Amazon ec2 centos), While login into iclock, I am getting error 404 in network log.

**While installing it on production server I followed below mentioned steps.**

1. Installation of apache tomcat 8.5.50 version (https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi)
2. Downloading iclock binaries from http://esslsecurity.com/catalog/softwares-0 -> epush server -> ePush Server Linux & Windows
3. keeping iclock folder in /opt/tomcat/webapps/iclock
4. starting tomcat using command /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start

I also tried it to install it on local system using same process and on local its workign fine.

Production URL : http://3.6.126.56:8080/iclock

Please find screenshots below
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research and changes in server configuration, I found that this issue was due to Java version installed on my server.

Installed java version was 1.7.0 and required version was 1.8.0 and above.

To check what versions are available on your system, use below command

**sudo update-alternatives --config java**

It will list all java versions available on your system. 
If required version is not available in list, then need to install it.

Change selection to required version as default version and restart tomcat server. Thanks to [policyx.com](https://www.policyx.com) team for the support